# move_base_flex and flexbe

Tags: ros-melodic, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Me and my team have been looking into the possibility of switching from move_base (http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) to move_base_flex (http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_flex), since this last one is compatible with SMACH state machines and would allow us to elaborate in more complex recovery mechanisms. Considering that mostly of our decision making is implemented using FlexBe (http://wiki.ros.org/flexbe), which expands SMACH in so many ways, We would like to know if it is possible to combine FlexBe with move_base_flex, in order to get the best of the two worlds. Although on paper it should be possible, is there any known limitation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370754/move_base_flex-and-flexbe/) by [joao.aguizo](https://answers.ros.org/users/61728/joao.aguizo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2021-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
short answer: yes. move_base_flex is what u need (or navigation2 if u are using ROS2).
I also use SMACH to call MBF actions; see [here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_smach/src/thorp_smach/states/navigation.py) some states I use. My states are very thin wrappers for smach_ros.SimpleActionState class, e.g. [this](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_smach/src/thorp_smach/states/navigation.py#L126) is my wrapper for MoveBase action. U may need to add a GetPath and Recovery states to call these other MBF actions, but it will be trivial (or I can add them, if you are not sure how to). Or you can include smach_ros.SimpleActionState and provide the action details directly, if you don't need any extra functionality.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2021-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joao.aguizo](https://answers.ros.org/users/61728/joao.aguizo/) on 2021-04-16**:
Hello Jorge, thank you very much for your input. Me and my team will definitely take a look into this possibility.